# How can I declare an argument in Kotlin that accepts (only) enums

Tags: java, exception, enums, kotlin

For example: I want to declare an exception:

```
class UnexpectedEnumException(enum: Enum...) : Exception("Unexpected enum $enum")
```

In Java I can do this by

```
public class UnexpectedEnumException extends RuntimeException {

    public UnexpectedEnumException(Enum<?> en) {
        super("Unexpected enum " +  en);
    }
```

Comment: `enum: Enum<*>`

Comment: You can also make the class generic based on the enum as well if you wanted: `class UnexpectedEnumException<T : Enum<T>>(enum: T)`

Answer (score 4):

To expand on JB Nizet's comment, which should have been an answer, [generics in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) are a little bit different from Java. The usage of the *star* is explained in the [Star projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) section of documentation.

```
class UnexpectedEnumException(enum: Enum<*>)
    : Exception("Unexpected enum $enum")
```